# How to Increment a FileName in batch? (Part2)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I already tried the answer given by Mofi in my last question regarding this topic. But I changed the base name and it does not seem to work by now. If you want to see the previous question:[How do I increment a filename in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201500/how-do-i-increment-a-filename-in-batch/39202093#39202093) What is wrong with this new code? It does not make a new file it just overwrites the previous made file.

```
:MainProcessNew
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
for /F %%G in (*.json) do ( 
 set "FileName=%%G"
 set "BaseName=Device"
 set "FileNumber=0"
)   

:FileNameLoop
set /A FileNumber+=1
if exist "%BaseName%%FileNumber%.json" (
 goto FileNameLoop
 ) 

echo.>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%BaseName%%FileNumber%.json"
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add which *.json files the user's desktop folder contains at the moment and which *.json files it should contain after running this batch file once. I don't see any reason why this batch code should not produce `Device1.json`, `Device2.json`, ... in desktop folder of user account active on running this batch file. BTW: Run as administrator means running with a different user account.

Comment: There is an existing .json file in Desktop named as Device.json but if I run the script, it just overwrites the contents of Device.json with the new data I just inputted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increment a filename in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201500/how-do-i-increment-a-filename-in-batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure the batch code in question is not complete or reduced to a script code not really suitable to reproduce the problem because with `Device.json` existing in folder `Desktop` and no other `Device*.json` file existing, the empty line is first written to `Device1.json`. A file with name `Device.json` is never overwritten by the batch code in question because variable `FileNumber` has always at least the value `1`.

Well, the **FOR** option `/F` is most likely wrong here as I suppose the **FOR** loop should search for *.json files as done without `/F`. Using a wildcard pattern like *.json together with option`/F` results in error message:

> The system cannot find the file *.json.

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` or `help for` for help on syntax of this command.

It is completely unclear what is the purpose of the **FOR** loop because the `FileName` variable is not used at all. This variable should perhaps hold the name of last found *.json if there was any *.json file found at all. But that also does not make sense if not further used anywhere.

It is also unclear why `BaseName` and `FileNumber` are defined inside the loop and not outside.

In the complete batch code the label `FileNameLoop` is perhaps the beginning of a subroutine. But in the reduced batch code in question there is no `call :FileNameLoop "%%G"` which I would expect in this case.

So the question is hard to answer as it is unclear what is really the problem with posted batch code.

```
:MainProcessNew
cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"

rem Useless FOR loop without /F commented out.
rem for %%G in (*.json) do set "FileName=%%G"

set "BaseName=Device"
set "FileNumber="

rem Skip searching for files with a file number
rem after Device if there is no Device.json file.
if not exist "%BaseName%.json" goto CreateFile

rem Otherwise keep Device.json as is and search for Device1.json,
rem Device2.json, ... until a Device*.json file with current number
rem is not found and use this number for next Device*.json file.
set "FileNumber=0"

:FileNameLoop
set /A FileNumber+=1
if exist "%BaseName%%FileNumber%.json" goto FileNameLoop

:CreateFile
rem Note: FileNumber is replaced in the line below by an empty
rem       string if there is no Device.json in desktop folder.
echo.>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%BaseName%%FileNumber%.json"
```

Hint: For debugging a batch file

1. comment out or remove all `@echo off` or `echo off` in the batch file or change `off` to `on`,
2. open a command prompt window,
3. enter `"Path to batch file\BachFileName.bat"` and press <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

Now it can be seen in the command prompt window each line executed by Windows command processor **after preprocessing each line and each command block** which means after replacing all `%VariableName%` by the current value of the variable in current line or entire command block.

And error messages can be also seen as the command prompt window remains open after processing batch file stopped, except it contains the command `exit` without option `/B` which always terminates the current command process.

Comment: It seems all of the comments are right. There is nothing wrong with the loop. There was an error in labels that I put in the earlier part of the code. Thank you again Mofi,for the tip in debugging. I was able to see the errors